# Run jCarouselLite again, after an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, livequery, jcarousellite

I am using jCarouselLite to show a post scroller, which loads posts from a specific category. But, I want to be able to switch the category via AJAX.

So, I load up everything in a div, and then run:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("#serviceNews").jCarouselLite({
    vertical: true,
    hoverPause:true,
    visible: 2,
    auto:2000,
    speed:1000
});
```

});

And it works... up until ajax refreshes the innerHTML of the #serviceNews. Then jCarouselLite stops working. I've tried using livequery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("#serviceNews").livequery(function(){
    $(this).jCarouselLite({
        vertical: true,
        hoverPause:true,
        visible: 2,
        auto:2000,
        speed:1000
    });
});
```

});

But the same thing happens. I am not very familiar with jQuery, so I'm probably missing out something obvious.

You can find the demo [here](http://dev.web2core.com/jugoistok/?lang=lat) (the middle column, below the banner, with the switchCategory buttons below the scroller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope you are using the latest code https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite

the documentation mentions here that you could end the carousel with

```
$('div.carousel').trigger('endCarousel')
```

So every time you need to update the carousel just endCarousel and then again bind the jCarouselLite to the div

Answer (score 1):

The solution from maniac_user is working for me.

Try to set a :

```
$("div.carousel").trigger("endCarousel");
```

Before your jCarousel code :

```
$(".auto .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
  speed: 14700,
  btnNext: ".next",
  vertical: true,
  hoverPause:true,
  visible: 1
});
```